# Replace the blanks with latest value if that sector

Tags: r, dataframe

Replace all the blanks with last weeks price of that sector, how do I do it in R. Can some one please help in giving a quick solution. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Input data frame is

```
sec     date      price
sec11   6/1/2019    309
sec12   7/1/2019    412
sec13   8/1/2019    206
sec14   9/1/2019    103
sec15   10/1/2019   257.5
sec16   11/1/2019   803.4
sec17   12/1/2019   638.6
sec11   13/1/2019   300
sec12   14/1/2019   400
sec13   15/1/2019   200
sec14   16/1/2019   100
sec15   17/1/2019   250
sec16   18/1/2019   780
sec17   19/1/2019   620
sec11   20/1/2019   
sec12   21/1/2019   
sec13   22/1/2019   
sec14   23/1/2019   
sec15   24/1/2019   
sec16   25/1/2019   
sec17   26/1/2019
```

output:

```
sec     date      price
sec11   6/1/2019    309
sec12   7/1/2019    412
sec13   8/1/2019    206
sec14   9/1/2019    103
sec15   10/1/2019   257.5
sec16   11/1/2019   803.4
sec17   12/1/2019   638.6
sec11   13/1/2019   300
sec12   14/1/2019   400
sec13   15/1/2019   200
sec14   16/1/2019   100
sec15   17/1/2019   250
sec16   18/1/2019   780
sec17   19/1/2019   620
sec11   20/1/2019   300
sec12   21/1/2019   400
sec13   22/1/2019   200
sec14   23/1/2019   100
sec15   24/1/2019   250
sec16   25/1/2019   780
sec17   26/1/2019   620
```

Comment: turn blanks into NAs and use `zoo::na.locf` ...

Comment: `na.locf` would fill with the last non-NA entry

Comment: @bob1 `zoo::na.locf` works just fine when you apply it by `sec`; another option is `tidyr::fill` (see my answer below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Option 1: `tidyr::fill` with `dplyr::group_by`

This can be a simple matter of `fill` with `group_by` in the `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    group_by(sec) %>%
    fill(price) %>%
    ungroup()
#
## A tibble: 21 x 3
#   sec   date      price
#   <fct> <fct>     <dbl>
# 1 sec11 6/1/2019    309
# 2 sec11 13/1/2019   300
# 3 sec11 20/1/2019   300
# 4 sec12 7/1/2019    412
# 5 sec12 14/1/2019   400
# 6 sec12 21/1/2019   400
# 7 sec13 8/1/2019    206
# 8 sec13 15/1/2019   200
# 9 sec13 22/1/2019   200
#10 sec14 9/1/2019    103
## ... with 11 more rows
```

In above output, rows have been reordered, so to see that this indeed reproduces your expected output we can add row numbers and order the final output by the original row numbers

```
 df %>%
    rowid_to_column() %>%
    group_by(sec) %>%
    fill(price) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    arrange(rowid) %>%
    select(-rowid) %>%
    as.data.frame()
#        sec      date price
#1  sec11  6/1/2019 309.0
#2  sec12  7/1/2019 412.0
#3  sec13  8/1/2019 206.0
#4  sec14  9/1/2019 103.0
#5  sec15 10/1/2019 257.5
#6  sec16 11/1/2019 803.4
#7  sec17 12/1/2019 638.6
#8  sec11 13/1/2019 300.0
#9  sec12 14/1/2019 400.0
#10 sec13 15/1/2019 200.0
#11 sec14 16/1/2019 100.0
#12 sec15 17/1/2019 250.0
#13 sec16 18/1/2019 780.0
#14 sec17 19/1/2019 620.0
#15 sec11 20/1/2019 300.0
#16 sec12 21/1/2019 400.0
#17 sec13 22/1/2019 200.0
#18 sec14 23/1/2019 100.0
#19 sec15 24/1/2019 250.0
#20 sec16 25/1/2019 780.0
#21 sec17 26/1/2019 620.0
```

---

### Option 2: `zoo::na.locf` with base R's `ave`

```
library(zoo)
transform(df, price = ave(price, sec, FUN = function(x) na.locf(x)))
#     sec      date price
#1  sec11  6/1/2019 309.0
#2  sec12  7/1/2019 412.0
#3  sec13  8/1/2019 206.0
#4  sec14  9/1/2019 103.0
#5  sec15 10/1/2019 257.5
#6  sec16 11/1/2019 803.4
#7  sec17 12/1/2019 638.6
#8  sec11 13/1/2019 300.0
#9  sec12 14/1/2019 400.0
#10 sec13 15/1/2019 200.0
#11 sec14 16/1/2019 100.0
#12 sec15 17/1/2019 250.0
#13 sec16 18/1/2019 780.0
#14 sec17 19/1/2019 620.0
#15 sec11 20/1/2019 300.0
#16 sec12 21/1/2019 400.0
#17 sec13 22/1/2019 200.0
#18 sec14 23/1/2019 100.0
#19 sec15 24/1/2019 250.0
#20 sec16 25/1/2019 780.0
#21 sec17 26/1/2019 620.0
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "sec     date      price
sec11   6/1/2019    309
sec12   7/1/2019    412
sec13   8/1/2019    206
sec14   9/1/2019    103
sec15   10/1/2019   257.5
sec16   11/1/2019   803.4
sec17   12/1/2019   638.6
sec11   13/1/2019   300
sec12   14/1/2019   400
sec13   15/1/2019   200
sec14   16/1/2019   100
sec15   17/1/2019   250
sec16   18/1/2019   780
sec17   19/1/2019   620
sec11   20/1/2019   ''
sec12   21/1/2019   ''
sec13   22/1/2019   ''
sec14   23/1/2019   ''
sec15   24/1/2019   ''
sec16   25/1/2019   ''
sec17   26/1/2019   ''   ", header = T)
```